# Website not showing on lan but shows on host computer

Tags: linux, nginx, networking

I made a nginx server at 192.168.1.106 and I can access it from the host computer but it doesn't show when I access it on a computer in the same network. But I can ssh into the server from a different computer using the same address. I checked my firewall to make sure it isn't blocking anything.

How do I access the server form a different computer?

```
> iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server_namedocs directive is used to identify virtual hosts, they're not used to set the binding.

netstat tells you that nginx listens on 0.0.0.0:80 which means that it will accept connections from any IP.

If you want to change the IP nginx binds on, you have to change the listendocs rule.
So, if you want to set nginx to bind to localhost, you'd change that to:

listen 127.0.0.1:80;
In this way, requests that are not coming from localhost are discarded (they don't even hit nginx).

Comment: I'm trying to access the server on a different computer, not trying to block everything except localhost.

Comment: yes but makes sure you haven't blocked it already, on LAN ip works differently try binding your nginx to your ip. on LAN You Can't access with localhost or system ip you have to add a listin ip to nginx config file.